# searchsphinx конфигурация (местоположение записей)

Tags: php, apache, sphinx

При настройке сфинкса запускаю sudo indexer --all
в итоге вижу надпись (последний блок:)

```
WARNING: collect_hits: mem_limit=0 kb too low, increasing to 24576 kb
collected 0 docs, 0.0 MB
total 0 docs, 0 bytes
total 0.000 sec, 0 bytes/sec, 0.00 docs/sec
total 9 reads, 0.000 sec, 14.8 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
total 33 writes, 0.000 sec, 9.0 kb/call avg, 0.0 msec/call avg
```

то-есть есть 33 записи, вопрос куда он их делает? это же в какие-то файлы или как?

Answer (score 1):

попробуйте отследить, к каким файлам обращается вызываемая программа (в вашем случае — `indexer`).

посмотреть, к каким файлам обращается программа можно, например, с помощью программы `strace`. пример отслеживания обращений программы `ls`:

```
$ strace -e open ls > /dev/null

open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY)      = 3
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/librt.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1", O_RDONLY) = 3
open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE) = 3
open(".", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_LARGEFILE|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache", O_RDONLY) = 3
```

здесь вызов самой программы, как в данном случае несущественный, перенаправляется в «пропасть»: `> /dev/null`.

как видите, большинство обращений — к библиотекам в режиме «только для чтения» (`O_RDONLY`).

если программа (предположительно) порождает «дочерние» процессы (функцией `fork()`), то для отслеживания **и** этих процессов можно добавить опцию `-f`:

```
$ strace -f -e open ls > /dev/null
```

если для работы отслеживаемой программы требуется `sudo`, то и `strace` надо запускать так же:

```
$ sudo strace -e open ls > /dev/null
```