# Где найти информацию о файлах,к которым обращался процесс?

Tags: linux, файловая-система, процесс

Стоит задача - узнать к каким файлам обращался процесс с заданным PID. Проблема состоит в том,что если после запуска процесса проверить `/proc/{PID}/fd` , `/proc/{PID}/maps` , я не увижу всех обращений к файлам , поскольку процесс открывает файл,читает из него информацию,заносит в буфер(насколько я это представляю) и закрывает файл в считанные доли секунды,таким образом не получится вытащить данные из открытого дескриптора,прежде чем он закроется,даже если автоматизировать этот процесс(написать скрипт). 
Вопрос: Где я могу посмотреть информацию о файлах(что это за файлы,пути к ним),к которым обращался процесс,но успел закрыть?

Comment: Запустить с strace?

Comment: похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/435316/178576

Answer (score 6):

к примеру, можно воспользоваться программой *strace* с опцией `-e open`:

```
$ strace -e open программа [аргументы]
```

---

например:

```
$ strace -o /tmp/лог.открытий.файлов -e open ls / >/dev/null
$ cat /tmp/лог.открытий.файлов
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/proc/filesystems", O_RDONLY)     = 3
open("/usr/lib/locale/locale-archive", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/", O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK|O_DIRECTORY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

---

у программы *strace* ещё много разных опций. см.:

```
$ man strace
```

для упомянутой ситуации, вероятно, полезной будет опция `-f` (или даже `-ff`), позволяющая отслеживать и порождаемые дочерние процессы.

Comment: добавлю, что для полноты картины полезно отслеживать также менее распространённые вызовы: `openat` и `creat`.

Answer (score 2):

В копилку

```
lsof (1)             - list open files

~$ lsof --help 2>&1 | grep PID
  -O no overhead *RISKY*   -P no port names           -R list paRent PID
  -p s   exclude(^)|select PIDs         -S [t] t second stat timeout (15)
```

Можно использовать если нужно отладить сервис или долго играющий процесс.

Comment: +1, пригодится )